# Evaluate $a^7+b^7+c^7+\dfrac {1}{a^7}+\dfrac {1}{b^7}+\dfrac {1}{c^7}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Let $a,b,c$ be the distinct complex roots of $P(x)=x^3-x-1$ . Evaluate $$a^7+b^7+c^7+\dfrac {1}{a^7}+\dfrac {1}{b^7}+\dfrac {1}{c^7}$$

**My approach**

According to Vieta formulae we have that $abc=1$ and $a+b+c=0$ and $ab+bc+ac=-1$ . Hence

$$-1=ab+bc+ac=\frac {ab+bc+ac}{abc}=\frac {1}{a}+\frac {1}{b}+\frac {1}{c}$$

So, here is my thought. I'm considering expanding $\bigg(\dfrac {1}{a}+\dfrac {1}{b}+\dfrac {1}{c}\bigg)^7=-1$ and  $(a+b+c)^7=0$ together to derive $\dfrac {1}{a^7}+\dfrac {1}{b^7}+\dfrac {1}{c^7}$ and $a^7+b^7+c^7$. The only tricky part is that these expansions are so messed up and complicated.  Should I continue on this path? Is it really reasonable ?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) is a recurrence that will help you.

Comment: There is a simple recursive formula for computing $s_k=a^k+b^k+c^k$ as $a_{k+3}=a_{k+1}+a_k$

Comment: It is $4(a+b+c)+6$.

Comment: Or, [$x^7=(x^4+x^2+x+1)(x^3-x-1)+2x^2+2x+1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=long+division+x%5E7+by+x%5E3-x-1) so you can substitute $a,b,c$ and use the fact that they are zeros of $x^3-x-1$ to conclude $a^7+b^7+c^7=2(a^2+b^2+c^2)+2(a+b+c)+3$. Similarly, convince yourself that $\frac{1}{a}, \frac{1}{b}, \frac{1}{c}$ are zeros of $x^3+x^2-1=0$ and use a [similar calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=long+division+x%5E7+by+x%5E3%2Bx%5E2-1) to conclude $\frac{1}{a^7}+\frac{1}{b^7}+\frac{1}{c^7}=\frac{2}{a^2}+\frac{2}{b^2}+\frac{2}{c^2}-3$...

Answer (score 6):

In this answer, we reach the solution without computing $a^7+b^7+c^7$ and $\dfrac {1}{a^7}+\dfrac{1}{b^7}+\dfrac {1}{c^7}$ separately .

---

Observe that,  $x=0$ is *not* a possible root of the polynomial $P(x)$ . Therefore, we can divide both sides of $P(x)=0$ by $x$ :

$$
\begin{align}&x^3-x-1=0\\
\iff &x^2-\frac 1x=1\end{align}
$$

Then, squaring both sides of the equation yields :

$$
\begin{align}&x^4-2x+\frac {1}{x^2}-1=0\\
\iff &x^6-2x^3-\left(x^2-1\right)=0\end{align}
$$

Since $x^2-1=\dfrac 1x$, we can rewrite the above equation as follows :

$$
\begin{align}&x^6-2x^3-\frac 1x =0\\
\iff &x^7-2x^4-1=0\end{align}
$$

Then, dividing both sides of the equation by $x^4$, leads to :

$$x^3-\frac {1}{x^4}=2$$

Again squaring of the both sides, yields :

$$x^6-\frac 2x+\frac {1}{x^8}=4$$

Then, multiplying both sides of the equation by $x$, we have :

$$x^7+\frac {1}{x^7}=4x+2$$

Finally we see that, the original summation is *equivalent* to :

$$
\begin{align}\sum_{x\in\{a,b,c\}}{\left(x^7+\frac {1}{x^7}\right)}&=\sum_{x\in\{a,b,c\}}(4x+2)\\
&=4(a+b+c)+6\\
&=6\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

which completes the answer .

Comment: I have seen this technique used in some previous answer of yours +1.

Answer (score 4):

Only the equation $x^3-x-1=0$ itself gives the reccurences:
$$x^3=x+1$$
$$x^4=x^2+x$$
$$x^5=x^3+x^2$$
$$x^5=x^2+x+1$$
$$x^7=x^4+x^3+x^2$$
$$x^7=2x^2+2x+1\tag1$$
Similarly, the equation for the reciprocal of roots $1-\frac1{x^2}-\frac1{x^3}=0$ gives:
$$\frac1{x^7}=\frac2{x^2}-1\tag2$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$, with $p_1=e_1=0$, $e_2=-1$, $p_{-1}=e_{-1}=-1$, $e_{-2}=0$:

$\begin{align}
p_7+p_{-7}&=2p_2+2p_1+3+2p_{-2}-3\\
&=2(p_1)^2-4e_2+2(p_{-1})^2-4e_{-2}\\
&=0-4(-1)+2(-1)^2-0=6
\end{align}$

where $p$ stands for the power sum and $e$ for the elemantary symmetric function of the roots of the corresponding equations.

Answer (score 0):

The roots of the polynomial $P(x)=x^3-x-1$ satisfy
$$x^3=x+1.$$
Use it twice to rewrite
$$x^7=x(x+1)^2=x^3+2x^2+x=2x^2+2x+1.$$
Therefore $$\color{red}{a^7+b^7+c^7}=2(\underbrace{a^2+b^2+c^2}_{2})+2(\underbrace{a+b+c}_0)+3
=\color{red}{7},$$
where $\;a^2+b^2+c^2=2\;$ follows from $$0=(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(\underbrace{ab+bc+ca}_{-1}).$$

The inverses of the roots of $P(x)$ satisfy the equation $$x^3=1-x^2.$$ Similarly as above we obtain
$$x^7=2x^2-1$$ with $x\in\big\{\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b},\frac{1}{c}\big\},$ hence
$$\color{red}{\frac{1}{a^7}+\frac{1}{b^7}+\frac{1}{c^7}}=2\bigg(\underbrace{\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}}_{1}\bigg)-3
=\color{red}{-1},$$ which gives the final result $6.$

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to manipulate using $x^3=x+1$.

$$x^7=x\cdot x^6=x(x+1)^2=x^3+2x^2+x=2x^2+2x+1$$

$$ \frac1{x^7}=\frac{(x^3-x)^2}{x(x+1)^2}=x(x-1)^2=x^3-2x^2+x=-2x^2+2x+1$$

$$\therefore x^7+\frac1{x^7}=4x+2, \quad \implies \sum_{a,b,c} \left(x^7+\frac1{x^7}\right)=4\sum_{a,b,c}x+6=6$$